# No. of hits on Website using c#

Tags: .net

Could anyone helps me by giving the answer for my question.
Here is the question...
How can we count the number of hits on our website for the day using c#

Thanks,
Bharath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a counter and a persistence way to keep the values. This can be a File or Database.

**The code below is for learning proposes**, you should use an existing service for this as it's much more efficiency and you will not have **lock** problems if to many hits happen in the same time

create a new Class for example:

```
public static class PageHitCounter
{
  private String fileTemplate = "dailyHits_{0:yyyyMMdd}.txt";
  private DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

  public static void Add() 
  {
    // we'll create one file per day
    // lets append a new user hit to a file
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(getFilename(now), true);
    // let's write the date and something else, f.ex. the browser info
    tw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy};{1}", 
                               now, 
                               Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    // close the file
    tw.Close();
  }

  public static int Count(DateTime day) 
  {
    int hits = 0;
    // let's open the file and count how many lines, 
    //    as we are adding one line per hit
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(getFilename(day)))
      while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
        hits++;
    return hits;
  }

  private string getFilename(Datetime day) 
  { 
    return Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + String.Format(fileTemplate, day));
  }
}
```

in Code:

```
Page_Load(...) {

    PageHitCounter.Add();

}
```

when you want to see how many hits, you can use

```
PageHitCounter.Count( DateTime.Now );
```

If you have a lot of pages and don't want to do this on each one, and assuming your project is WebForms, you can create a MasterPage and append this `Add()` to the MasterPage `OnLoad` event or you can create your own page and implement the code.

---

**As an option** to your real problem, you can use [**Woopra** service](http://www.woopra.com/) for live results, I use in some forums and it's quite lovely see all users, you just need to create an account and use their javascript code in all your footer (normally we use a master page and just append in one file)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [google analytics account](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and place the javascript on your site. then google analytics will do it for you

Comment: No but you get so much more by using google analytics and its free/easy/simple!

Comment: Google does not give you the live results ... only after 48 hours!

Comment: True but its more useful in the long run and why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I kinda prefer [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/) for small forums and little websites (**small** cause I use the free version), it's way more fun to see live users :)

Comment: Never used it. Will check it out tho :)

Comment: you will like the fun of it, and you can pass the `username` or any unique `name` and see that name in Woopra Client, you know exactly who is he :D

Answer (score 0):

There must be an embedded code in your web pages to count the number of hits. Directly you can't access this info.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for your website, or is this a class assignment?

There are plenty of existing tools that will give you a lot of information on the number of hits, types of visitors, various metrics about their behaviour, etc, etc...it's far more practical but not in C#.

If this is a class assignment - you could increment a counter on your website and persist it to the file system or a database.

Here is a CodePlex example you could look at and modify to track hits daily.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/EasyHit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Read article, this may be helpful to you

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/238/howto-create-a-hit-counter-using-a-database-in-aspnet-1x-with-c-sharp

This developed with with C# and Microsoft Access database.
But for better performance use SQL database